# Is it possible to have a DOT as a part of a field name in JSON being used with Mustache?

Tags: mustache

I have some JSON that I retrieve from another service and it returns some fields like this

`{"name": {"first.name": "Peter", "surname": "smith"}}`

My JSON encoder handles it fine, but Mustache (I'm using the Synopse implementation) cant handle it as I'd like (its likely not legal syntax I suspect). A Mustache line of

`{{name.first.name}}`

obviously expects something like `{"name":{"first": {"name": "Peter"}}}` and translates to empty. I have tried escaping it with a backslash but that doesn't work.

Is this JSON simply not considered valid or is there a way to correctly escape the Mustache line to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I have concluded that having dots in the field name isnt really something that can be supported. I'm taking steps to have the source data reformatted so it doesn't have the dots in it.

This is mostly based on jpow javascript interprets variables. I doubt it could diferentiate between class separators and dots that were part of the field.